# Click link to specific bootstrap tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Is there a way I can click on a link and have it go to another page and open a specific bootstrap tab?

Here is my html:

```
<a href="/admin/#tab2">View Tab 2</a>
```

And on my /admin route I have the bootstrap tab:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Completed</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Confirmed</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Shipped</a></li>
</ul>
```

Upon clicking my link, I want the app to go to the /admin route and show the contents of `#tab2`. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. But it will require some custom jQuery.

First you will need your link to open in a new tab by using `target="_blank"`

```
<a target="_blank" href="/admin/#tab2">View Tab 2</a>
```

Then, on the page you are going to, will need to trigger that tab to open. You can do that using this code (where the tabs has the id "myTabs"):

```
$('#myTabs a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').tab('show')
```

More info on their website: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 1):

I've had to implement something similar and the following plugin helped me a ton: http://www.aidanlister.com/2014/03/persisting-the-tab-state-in-bootstrap/

Basically, it's a lightweight jQuery plugin that implements tab activation based on URL, back button support, and URL updates when each tab is clicked (so your users can share links).

It's called on the `nav-tabs` element like so:

```
$('.nav-tabs-sticky').stickyTabs();
```